# Dealing with recursion (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm a having some problems trying to do some business logic for a client (web trading):

My client has a table (simplified) like this one:

```
|| ID ||  OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID  || DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID ||
|| 01 ||  34                  || 45                  ||
|| 01 ||  34                  || 16                  ||
|| 01 ||  45                  || 57                  ||
|| 01 ||  47                  || 57                  ||
|| 01 ||  57                  || 63                  ||
|| 01 ||  16                  || 20                  ||
```

Now, the app must show the largest trade chain, a trade chain is defined as the relation within offered and demanded products.

This are trade chains:

< 34, 45, 57, 63> <34, 16, 20> <45, 57, 63> <47, 57, 63> <57, 63> <16, 20>

I try to use C# to solve this, but given the volume of data it became impossible. A coworker of mine told recommends me to use recursion. I try to understand what he means, but I'm a client side developer, with no much knowledge of SQL.

I did these:

```
  select  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID
  from TRADES o
  start with 
  o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = (SELECT MIN(o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID) from TRADES)
  connect by NOCYCLE prior o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID;
```

I'm trying to start the recursion with the oldest product on the system (with the min identifiers). But It doesn't work. It gave me all the trade chains. I need just the largest one.

Heres an output example:

```
OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID      DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID

9920896475501851        59587794888502550724
59587794888502550724    13197303523502765990
13197303523502765990    54010274740204405159
54010274740204405159    14505831337880766413
14505831337880766413    89607128670993987443
89607128670993987443    8802863939059413452
8802863939059413452  7779127922701247342
7779127922701247342  3810800421539873909
3810800421539873909  12423373218147473557
```

Comment: I think you need to switch where your `prior` is, maybe? As in: `connect by NOCYCLE o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = prior  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID;`

Comment: Nop. It works with the actual order. It just that doesn't return the longest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the trade chain is equal to the depth of the recursion. Oracle has a psuedo variable, LEVEL, that you can use. If you take your original query and sort by LEVEL desending the end of the longest chain will be first. Then we need to eliminate the rest of the query.

```
select *
  from
  ( select  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID
      from TRADES o
      start with    o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = 
                (SELECT MIN(o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID) from TRADES)
      connect by NOCYCLE prior o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID
      order by level desc
   )
  where rownum = 1;
```

`The above will return the last row in the chain. To get the entire chain in a comma seperated list:

select lvl,   opath ||','|| DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID chain
from (
select level lvl,  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, ',') opath
  from TRADES o
  start with    o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = (SELECT MIN(o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID) from TRADES)connect by NOCYCLE prior o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID
  order by level desc
)
where rownum = 1`

You may want to remove the leading comma.

If you want the longest chain, one row at a time:

```
select c.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, c.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID
  from TRADES c
  start with  (c.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID,  c.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID) in
            (
             select o1,  d1
              from (
                       select level lvl,  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID
                          , CONNECT_BY_ROOT OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID   o1
                          , CONNECT_BY_ROOT DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID   d1
                         from TRADES o
                         start with    o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID not in (select st.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID from trades st)
                         connect by NOCYCLE prior o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID
                        order by level desc
                    )
                  where rownum = 1
            )
   connect by NOCYCLE prior c.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = c.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID
```

The `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` command gets data from the root of the recursion, i.e., the first row of the chain. I'm running on 10g Rel 2. I'm not sure if it's available on older versions.

Comment: Hi. It starts to execute but doesn't respond anything. (I'm trying within the local lan. There are only 20k entries :S

Comment: @Randolf R-F: Check the statement you entered. When I add level to the select list and run it against the data you gave in the question it returns one row (3  57  63). This is the last line of the longest chain. But you want the entire chain, right?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want something like

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with trades as (
  2    select 34 offered_product_id, 45 demanded_product_id from dual
  3    union all
  4    select 34, 16 from dual
  5    union all
  6    select 45, 57 from dual
  7    union all
  8    select 47, 57 from dual
  9    union all
 10    select 57, 63 from dual
 11    union all
 12    select 16, 20 from dual
 13  )
 14  select path
 15    from (
 16    select offered_product_id,
 17           demanded_product_id,
 18           level + 1,
 19           sys_connect_by_path( offered_product_id, '/' ) ||
 20              '/' || demanded_product_id path,
 21           dense_rank() over (order by level desc) rnk
 22      from trades
 23   connect by prior demanded_product_id = offered_product_id )
 24*  where rnk = 1
SQL> /

PATH
--------------------
/34/45/57/63
```

Comment: +1 the select statement is a good answer and the provided with clause is handy to mock the real db data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can't try. It says: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

Comment: @Randolf - How long are your actual trade chains?  It sounds like from the error SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH is trying to generate a string longer than 4000 characters.  You could eliminate that call (in which case you wouldn't get the path any longer) or you could find some other way to represent the path (perhaps there is a PRODUCT table with a shorter identifier you could join to?).

Comment: Nop. There isn't one :( If i remove the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, then it starts to execute, but never stop. I add the NOCYCLE clause, but even then it doesn't stop :(

Comment: Define "doesn't stop".  I would imagine that the TRADES table is likely rather large-- it may take a while for the query to run.

Comment: I let the oracle sql developer open for about 20 mins. But it didn't response. Maybe the problem is within the starts with? I select the min id based on the think that is better to start with the first trade. Maybe that is wrong?

Comment: OK, so the query takes more than 20 minutes.  How big is the table?  What is the query plan?  What is the session waiting on?

Comment: Table has only 20.000 records. I'm probing it here connected by lan and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `start with` clause you have does almost nothing because the "o." correlates it to the main query. It is equivalent to `start with    o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID is not null`. I think you want:

`select level,  o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID, ','), SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID, ',')
   , CONNECT_BY_ROOT OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID   o1
   , CONNECT_BY_ROOT DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID   d1
  from TRADES o
  start with    o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID not in (select st.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID from trades st)
  connect by NOCYCLE prior o.DEMANDED_PRODUCT_ID = o.OFFERED_PRODUCT_ID`

The above will give you all chains but won't start any chain "in the middle." If you only want the longest chain you clearly don't want the shorter chains that start "in the middle."